# Write formatted result from ssh2_exec on txt with php

Tags: php, shell, formatted, ssh2-exec

I tried with php to write on a txt file the result of command 'df -h'.

```
$comand = 'df -h';
$stream = ssh2_exec ( $connection, $comand );
stream_set_blocking ( $stream, true );
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream ( $stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO );
$stream_result = stream_get_contents ( $stream_out );
file_put_contents('result.txt',$stream_result);
```

If I run the command on the shell I have a formatted text and it is what I would like but if I do it from php and save it in a file I get it unformatted

This is what i got:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_algosec-OS
                       28G   18G  9.4G  65% /
tmpfs                 7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             969M   46M  873M   5% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_algosec-data
                       84G   56G   24G  70% /data
```

This is what i would like:

```
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                       7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          7.9G  3.3G  4.7G  41% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          7.9G  266M  7.6G   4% /run
tmpfs                          7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cl_svlcht3cm-root  214G  174G   40G  82% /
/dev/sda1                     1014M  267M  748M  27% /boot
```